# Using javascript filtering when having 2 arrays to check or compare

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filtering

I have some problems using the filtering method in javascript when I have two large objects and have to compare them in a filtering process.

For simplicity, I created an example, where we have two arrays: array_1 and array_2.

Array_2 should be filtered based on the id that exists in array_1. (These id's are the same in each array)

```
let array_1 = [
    { id: '_i23455szq', description: 'text' }, 
    { id: '_h6yf2uk1n', description: 'text' }
]

let array_2 = [
    { id: '_h6yf2uk1n', description: 'text', capacity: 2 },
    { id: '_465324423', description: 'text', capacity: 4 },
    { id: '_i23455szq', description: 'text', capacity: 0 },
    { id: '_54234gfgd', description: 'text', capacity: 0 },
]
```

As you see, in array_2 we have a capacity set. I'm trying to filtering based on capacity, I want to filter array_2 so after the filtering, it includes every object that has a capacity (higher than 0, but also include those that matches the once in array_1)

How can this be done, if you should make a nice solution without too many for loops?

Is this even possible in 1-2 lines?

Have tried with a filtering and a forEach inside, but can't seem to create a solution that is simply a don't take up so much space.

```
array_2 = array_2.filter(function (i) {
    array_1.forEach(j => {
        if (j.id == i.id) {
            console.log("ID matches")
            // How to return??
        }
    })
})
```

The output should be the following objects:

```
{ id: '_h6yf2uk1n', description: 'text', capacity: 2 },
{ id: '_465324423', description: 'text', capacity: 4 },
{ id: '_i23455szq', description: 'text', capacity: 0 },
```

Comment: Why is the second object included, the id `_465324423` is not present in the first array?

Comment: Because it has a capacity higher than 0 , so if one matches from arrray_1 but has a capacity of 0, it should also be included.

Comment: Ah, so the condition is an *or*, not an *and*, got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably best to make a `Set` of `array_1`'s `id`s in advance (`Set` lookup is much faster than any other sort of `.some` / `indexOf` array lookup). Then, you just need to `.filter`, extracting the `id` and `capacity` properties from `array2`, and check to see if the `id` is in the Set of ids, or if the capacity is greater than 0. This has a complexity of `O(N)`, while using array methods like `.some` inside the `.filter` would have `O(N^2)`:

```js
let array1 = [
    { id: '_i23455szq', description: 'text' }, 
    { id: '_h6yf2uk1n', description: 'text' }
]

let array2 = [
    { id: '_h6yf2uk1n', description: 'text', capacity: 2 },
    { id: '_465324423', description: 'text', capacity: 4 },
    { id: '_i23455szq', description: 'text', capacity: 0 },
    { id: '_54234gfgd', description: 'text', capacity: 0 },
]

const ids = new Set(array1.map(({ id }) => id));
console.log(
  array2.filter(({ id, capacity }) => ids.has(id) || capacity > 0)
);
```

Comment: Absolute beautiful answer, fast and short. Thanks, have a good day Sir.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a logical OR (`||`) of two conditions in your filter. Check the capacity first so that you don't need to search `array_1` if `capacity > 0`. If `capacity` isn't greater than `0` then youcan search for an object with the same `id` in `array_1`.

```js
const array_1 = [
    { id: '_i23455szq', description: 'text' }, 
    { id: '_h6yf2uk1n', description: 'text' }
]

const array_2 = [
    { id: '_h6yf2uk1n', description: 'text', capacity: 2 },
    { id: '_465324423', description: 'text', capacity: 4 },
    { id: '_i23455szq', description: 'text', capacity: 0 },
    { id: '_54234gfgd', description: 'text', capacity: 0 },
]

const result = array_2.filter( obj => 
  obj.capacity > 0 || array_1.some( ({ id }) => id === obj.id )
);

console.log( result );
```

Answer (score 0):

array_2 = array_2.filter(i => i.capacity || array_1.some(j => i.id == j.id));

Comment: Welcome to SO! can you please explain what are you trying to say?